# Selenium "Cannot login"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, authentication

I am unable to access through this lock icon and get to login. I have used different locator options.

[image]

The current code I am using:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("example.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("login-trigger")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("User1"); 
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123456");
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
```

Comment: What kind of error you are facing while doing this?

Comment: its not taking me anywhere

Comment: i cannot click on it so i can access login page

Comment: Isn't there any error in the console?

Comment: Check if the id 'submit' is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing `driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();`

try this : `driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`